# Windows 7 Home Premium how to download English speech recognition

Tags: speech-recognition

I would like to use speech recognition in English on my Windows 7 PC.

But my PC won't let me because it doesn't support the language that I use even though all my settings and other things are written with Danish and the speech recognition is also Danish. I found out that I only had one option for my Danish speech recognition and that is English, so I figured out why it didn't support the speech recognition - because the program is in Danish but the language is English.

So I was thinking about if I could install the English speech recognition? (I come from Denmark).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to indicate which exact edition of Windows 7 you are running.

Comment: Your edit appeared as from an Anonymous user -- you will have much more success with this site if you register your account. You can always edit your own questions and answers immediately.

Comment: You can't without Ultimate or Enterprise. You can either [buy a key](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00H09C0U2/ref=s9_al_bw_g65_i5?pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=center-3&pf_rd_r=0TS1PK1JTF6WXAKPPM9Y&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=1752383762&pf_rd_i=1286119011) and use the "Add more features to windows" menu to upgrade or do something [a little bit less legitimate](http://thepiratebay.se/torrent/6473801/Windows_7_Ultimate_Keygen_1.3.3.8_(x86_x64))

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Microsoft Answers](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/windows-7-speech-recognition-language-selection/0a859099-a76d-4799-abe9-847997399927) post:

> You can only use Speech Recognition in a different laguage if a MUI language pack is installed for one of the supported languages. The 35 MUI language packs are only available in the Ultimate and Enterprise editions of Windows 7.

So, unless you have one of those two versions, there isn't much you can do. However, I have used a program called [Vistalizator](http://www.froggie.sk/) that enables to bypass the version limitations of Windows 7 and install the MUI packs. According to the page, Vistalizator has the following relevant features:

> - Works in 32-bit and 64-bit Windows Vista/Windows 7
> - Uses official Microsoft Windows language packs
> - Compatible with Vista Service Pack 1/2 and Windows 7 Service Pack 1
> - User Account Control (UAC) compliant - prompts for administrative privileges
> - Windows Speech Recognition works with all supported languages: Chinese, English, French, German, Japanese and Spanish